# Why doesn't gorm report an insert error in the logs?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I tried performing an insert using GORM and my logs displays the insert statement and says

> 0 rows affected or returned

If I copy and paste the insert statement, I can see this error in psql:

> ERROR:  null value in column "start_dt" violates not-null constraint

**Is there a way for me to see this error in my go logs right away?**

Comment: Please post the code you have tried to insert the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use gorm in debug mode to see error messages!

```
// Enable Logger, show detailed log
db.LogMode(true)

// Disable Logger, don't show any log even errors
db.LogMode(false)

// Debug a single operation, show detailed log for this operation
db.Debug().Where("name = ?", "jinzhu").First(&User{})
```

[Gorm documentation for Logger](http://gorm.io/docs/logger.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to append `.Error` at the end of your insert statement in order for GORM to return the error message if there were any. Also, you can use `.GetErrors()` to get all raised errors as a slice.

Answer (score 0):

```
if err := db.Create(&entity).Error; err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.